# Meteor - delete from session on page change/reload

Tags: session, meteor

how do you deal with "volatile" values in Session? For example, I hold form validation errors in session. but I don't want them to be there on page refresh or after changing pages.

Answer (score 5):

Session variables do not survive a manual page refresh (ctrl+r). If you want some variables cleared after a page transition you could put the clearing code in your router or in your template's `destroyed` callback (I typically choose the latter). For example if you have a template called `signin` you could do:

```
Template.signin.destroyed = function(){
  Session.set('signinValidationErrors', null);
}
```

Whenever you naviate away from the signin page (the template is destroyed), it will clear `signinValidationErrors`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove Session variables after leaving the page, you can choose among these options:

```
Session.set('validationErrors', null);
// or
Session.keys.validationErrors = null;
// or
Session.keys['validationErrors'] = null;
// or
delete Session.keys.validationErrors;
// or
delete Session.keys['validationErrors'];
```

Whenever the user leaves the page the `onDestroyed` will execute. Put your choice there and it will clear the Session variable

```
Template.myPage.onDestroyed(function (){
    // put your choice here
});
```